# R: Use assigned name for a data frame in a for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dynamic, nested

I am working on the following for-loop in R:

```
for(i in dim(Test)[1]) { 
                 nam <- paste(Test[i,1])
                 assign(nam, as.data.frame(matrix(nrow=1,ncol=8)))
                        for (i in 1:dim(nam)[2]){
                         nam[,i]=round(data[,1]*M[1,i]+data[,2]*M[2,i]+data[,3]*M[3,i]+
                         data[,4]*M[4,i]+data[,5]*M[5,i]+data[,6]*M[6,i]+data[,7]*M[7,i]+
                         data[,8]*M[8,i])}}
```

However, I get the following Error Message:

```
Error in 1:dim(nam)[2] : argument of length 0
```

How can I rewrite dim(nam)[2] so it dinamically uses the name I assign to the data frame?

For completeness here are the data frames I am using:

```
rand.sum <- function(n){
x <- sort(runif(n-1))
c(x,1) - c(0,x)
 }

M <- t(replicate(8,rand.sum(8)))

test <- as.data.frame(t(replicate(1, rand.sum(10))))

ID <- c("ID")

data <- cbind(ID,test)
```

Comment: You can use `dim(get(nam))`. But you almost certainly **shouldn't**. Any time you are dynamically creating a name with a number, you should be using a list or vector instead; here, a list which can hold multiple data frames.

Comment: @dash2 Thank you for your comment. What is the reason to use a list? So i basically create a list in the for loop and assign the new data frames to it? - Sorry I pretty new to R that why I am asking this basic question

Comment: Turn it around: why would you not use a list? Because you like using `get` and `assign`, and pasting variable names together, instead of simply `test[[i]] <- ...`? Because you will never want to know how many data frames you have - `length(test)` - or do something to every data frame with `lapply`, or quickly select certain data frames using `Find` or `Filter`?

Comment: Sounds compelling! I have re-written the code as to your suggestion.